# Decimal in slider value

Tags: ios

I have a button that I press and a loop does:

```
    NSLog(@"on");
    sleep(slider.value);
    NSLog(@"off");
    sleep(slider.value);
```

However if I want to have the slider somewhere between 1 and 0 it either sleeps 1 second or not at all, how do I make it sleep half a second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sleep()` takes in seconds.  You want to do sub seconds, so try using `usleep()`, which will sleep in milliseconds (.001 of a second).  You may need to import `unistd.h`

So what you'd want to do is something like this:

```
usleep((int)(slider.value * 1000.0));
```